# React How to re render map function on change of variabel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-rgb-pisgg) is an excerpt which should show my problem. In my project I do something with the grid and now I want to reset it, but I dont know how it works because if I change the grid variable, the .map() function doesnt re render. I hope you understand my problem and you can help me.

### That is my code:

```
  export default function App() {
  const getInitialGrid = () => {
    const grid = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
      const currentRow = [];
      for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
        currentRow.push([]);
      }
      grid.push(currentRow);
    }
    return grid;
  };
  const grid = getInitialGrid();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {grid.map(function (row, rowIdx) {
        return (
          <div className="grid-row" key={rowIdx}>
            {row.map(function (node, colIdx) {
              return <div className="node">hi</div>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Its the same code like here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-rgb-pisgg)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: React components only rerender when state or props update (or its parent rerenders), this component has neither state nor props, so it will only rerender when its parent rerenders. Can you update your question to include the attempt to reset anything or update the grid?

Comment: Not sure, but you can move your `getInitialGrid` when component mounts, and remove it when unmounts, `useEffect(() => { setState(getInitialGrid()); return () => setState(); }, [])`, setting it to a new state `const [state, setState] = useState();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook for that.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
    // App code
    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(getInitialGrid());
    // more App code
```

then if you want to assign a new value to the grid and cause a rerender you do it like this (inside your App component):

```
setGrid(yourNewGrid);
```